# Clone / Push / Pull from two different Git accounts

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, gitlab, git-bash

So I have a personal Bitbuket account that I use to clone/push/pull from with not problem.
I'm using Git-Bash and did a global username and password with `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email`
Now I got a new account on Gitlab with different email and password, and I've created a new SSH-Key `id_rsa_gitlab` and added that SSH Key `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab` and to gitlab.lan account and I added that rule to the config file ...

```
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host gitlab
  HostName gitlab.lan
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab
```

But now when I try to clone from the Gitlab repo, I get this error ...

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.lan port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing here?
Do I need to change the global user.name and user.password or what?

Comment: is gitlab running on port 22? what happens if you run `ssh gitlab.lan` on the console?

Comment: @Ruby: Why don't you change just change the user.name and user.email for the repository (not global) and use the same SSH Key?

Comment: @Flurin: Port 22 is the ssh port or not?

Comment: Port 22 is typically the SSH port but most on-premise git packages listen on something else - that way server admins can still use port 22 for regular access.

Comment: @Flurin it print `ssh: connect to host gitlab.lan port 22: Connection timed out`

Comment: @Philj0: How can I do that?

Comment: @Ruby you can change it with ‚git config user.name „user“‘ and ‚git config user.email „E-Mail“‘

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check if your URL does takeadvantage of your `~/.ssh/config` entries.

If should be:

```
gitlab:project/repo.git
```

And `ssh -T gitlab` should print a Welcome message.

> added that SSH Key `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab` and to **`gitlab.com`** account

For that, make sure your hostname is `gitlab.com`, not `gitlab.lan` in the `config` file.
And make sure you have added the *public* key content (`~/.ssh/id_rsa_gitlab.pub`) to your gitlab.com user ssh settings.

I confirm that, in a company, outgoing queries with ssh are generally... blocked! In that case, using https is a better option.

Comment: Didn't work, the host is `gitlab.lan` not `gitlab.com`, and when I do `ssh -T gitlab` it print `ssh: connect to host gitlab.lan port 22: Connection timed out`

Comment: Then you need to sort out the SSH situation on the server side, gitlab.lan. it is clearly not listening.

Comment: By the way, I'm able to clone the repo over `http` just fine, could maybe the problem be in the Proxy settings I'm on? Although I'm able to use SSH with bitbucket.org just fine.

Comment: @Ruby proxy is for https, nothing to do with SSH. Bitbucket ssh clone means your firewall does not block SSH connection. So again, the issue lies on the server side "gitlab.lan" (wherever that is pointing to): its ssh daemon seems not active.

Comment: I think I found the same issue on this link ...
`https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/`
However, it's for `gitlab.com`, I tried it with `gitlab.lan` but didn't work.

Comment: @Ruby The link is https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/. What is the content of your ssh config file? And by the way, what is gitlab.lan?  Does it ping?

Comment: The content of config is what I posted in the main thread. and gitlab.lan doesn't ping, it returns `Request timed out.`, but yet again `gitlab.com` also doesn't ping.

Comment: I think the problem probably because I'm behind a proxy in my company. I settled with using `http` with gitlab.

Comment: @Ruby Yes, that is my experience also: no ssh allowed in my company either. I have edited the answer accordingly.